# Access the VuexStore in beforeEnter route

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I would like to redirect an unauthenticated user to the ‘/login’ route, and the auth user to the ‘/’ when he’ll try to access to the login page.

When the user is logged in, I put his information on the store to be easily retrieved.
When no user is logged in, the user authenticated informations on the store are still null.

So, in my beforeEnter of my ‘/login’ I would like to redirect him like this :slight_smile:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (store.getters.userAuthenticated != null) {
           next('/')
    } else {
           next()
    }
}
```

My problem in here is my userAuthenticated in the getters are always null, even if I am logged in.
When I put a console.log(store.getters) I see actual information in my userAuthenticated getters.

[image]

It seems the data in the beforeEnter is not synchronized with the actual data from the store.

How I would do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

That's how you do it

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let nextParams
  let pageRequiresAuth    = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  let userSignedIn        = store.getters['user/signedIn']

  if (pageRequiresAuth) {
    if (!userSignedIn) 
      nextParams = { path: paths.signInPath }  
  } else {
    if (userSignedIn)
      // don't let see auth pages after if user already signed in
      nextParams = { path: paths.afterSignInPath }
  }
  next(nextParams)
})
```